# How can I access values from keys from firebase in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to make a way to access the two keys that have the email and password of the user(key value pairs) with this code

```
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://fir-test-3631f.firebaseio.com/", None)
def postdata():
        global result
        name = input("What is your name?")
        data = {
                'Name': name,
                }
        result = firebase.post('/people/', data)
        print(result)

#postdata()

def getdata():
        result = firebase.get("/people", "")
        print(result)


getdata()
```

and it gives me this

```
{'-LnUhQ4LM2a9usw5ilfM': {'email': 'email@email.com', 'password': 'password'}}
```

What i'm trying to access (Imagine there is multiple users with their own emails)
are the values of all the keys, and then see if the users input (user inputs email and password into a text input) is the same as any of those values and if it is then it gives the user their details but I can't find anything like this on the web